# is there any command to change all font when i maximize windows in vb?

Tags: vb.net, fonts, font-size, maximize-window

In my program, my default font is fit to small windows but user can maximize windows and then all font is too small when user do that. I would like to increase all font size in all page of my program when user maximize a windows. I can change size for each text but there are too many text that i need to change. Is there any command to change all font in my program ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not messed about with the fonts in the controls, then they should all be linked via their ParentFont property. So all you have to do is assign a new font to the form they are on and they'll all happily follow suit.

Note you'll need to get your controls resizing properly as well.

Comment: i use Me.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", "12") ,and then all text have changed but not in label. it is still small size. Is there any way to do?

Comment: Works for me with labels as well, but if you have changed the label's font as some point, it won't. Delete one of them off the form and add it again. See what happens. Or have a look in the .designer file, there should be no font = etc for the components you want the behaviour on.

Comment: ps if the label is in a container e.g. panel and it is not pointing at parentfont, then it's the parent of the labels.